# Build server auto versioning endless loop

Tags: c#, svn, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

In the build script, we update the AssemblyFileVersion in a AssemblyInfo.cs file for multiple files.  Then, the build script commits the updated AssemblyInfo.cs files back to SVN.  Next, the CruiseControl.NET build server picks up the modifications, and the build.xml file is ran.  The process is caught in a loop.

How can the updated AssemblyInfo.cs files be committed without causing the build process to loop?

Answer (score 0):

do not push back the changes done on a buildserver into the source control repo. If for one reason or another, you can not do this, you can use the filter-sourcecontrol, to filter out changes made by a specific user

http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Filtered

Comment: Thank you for the response.  What do you recommend for saving auto generated versions?  Is there a preferred method?

Comment: I agree. Make the changes to the "local" AssemblyInfo.cs file only (aka, no need to commit those changes).  The simplest mapping is to use the SVN-Revision Number.  Then you know which SVN-Revision produced that DLL.

Comment: We filter out the file that gets auto-committed in the ccnet sourcecontrol block. So ccnet doesn't listen to it for changes.